# Is there any way to set a default value for cells when adding a new row in react material-table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

When I add a new row in my editable materital-table, I am trying to set the default value of the credits and numeric grade cells to be 0 instead of blank(see screenshot). There doesn't seem to be any sort of documentation on the material-table website for this [material-table.com](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable).

Answer (score 2):

There is a documentation on material-table.com
https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable

> You can use `column.initialEditValue` to set initialValue on adding new row.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying this using html input tag and 'text' type.  Whilst the default value displays ok when adding a new record, it is not getting added to my state.  A NULL value is sent.  You have to make an edit change in the input text box for the value to get recognised.
Any ideas?

Comment: same here, did you manage to figure it out ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom component like this:

```
{ 
  title: 'Credits', 
  field: 'courseCredits', 
  editComponent: (props) => (
    <Input 
      defaultValue={props.value || 0} 
      onChange={(e) => props.onChange(e.target.value)} 
      type="number"
    /> 
}
```

Comment: Do you need an import for the <Input /> tag or can you just put it in?

Comment: If you're using material-ui you could import textfield (https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#textfield-api), or just use standard html-inputfield (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)